# Find the coefficient of $x^{18}$ in $(x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5)(x^2 + x^3 + x^4 +\cdots)^5 $

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

> Find the coefficient of $x^{18}$ in $$(x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5)(x^2 + x^3 + x^4 +\cdots)^5 $$

This is the first time coming across a generating function question and am not quite sure how to solve this and am looking for some help, thanks!

Comment: Up till $x^5$ ?

Comment: i assume so, this is what the question has stated

Comment: $$ \begin{align}
& (x+x^2+x^3+\cdots)(x^2+x^3+x^4+\cdots)^5 \\ \\
= {} & \Big( x(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots)\Big)\Big( x^2(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots)\Big)^5 \\ \\
= {} & x^{11} (1+x+x^2+x^3 + \cdots)(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots)^5 \\ \\
= {} & x^{11} (1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots)^6
\end{align}$$
So the number of ways to write $18$ as the sum of six positive integers of which five are at least $2$ is the same as the number of ways to write $18-11=7$ as the sum of six nonnegative integers.

Order counts. I.e. $0+2+2+3+0+0$ is not the same as $2+0+2+0+0+3.$

Comment: Hint: $x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 = \frac{x (1-x^5)}{1-x}$ and $x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + \cdots = \frac{x^2}{1-x}$.

Comment: Think about how these expressions are expanded.  This breaks down into a scenario where you have in $6$ different subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ (one for the coefficients of each multiplicand) and you want to count how many ways you can get a sum of $15$ by choosing exactly one number from each subset.

Comment: @YoloInver u can still post it as an answer

Comment: @MichaelHardy is that a complete solution?

Comment: No, it does not work, there are $4$ terms in the first factor and $5$ in the second.

Comment: @DanielSchepler could you post an answer?

Comment: @jh123 : Does it look as if it's a complete solution? Does it leave you understanding the answer to the question you posed?

Comment: Oops, I meant to say "sum of $18$" above.

Comment: @MichaelHardy no it does noy

Comment: @jh123 : If it were a complete solution I would probably have posted it as an answer.

Comment: @MichaelHardy okay someone below has posted an answer using some of the techniques u began to use, so thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite your expression as $x^{11}(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\ldots)^5$ so you are looking for the coefficient of $x^7$ in $$(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\ldots)^5$$  This is the number of ways to write $7$ as the sum of six nonnegative integers with the first being at most four.  Stars and bars gives you the number without the restriction on the first as ${12 \choose 5}$.  Now subtract off the number of ways to express $2,1,0$ as five nonnegative integers, so we have $${12 \choose 5}-{6 \choose 4}-{5 \choose 4}-{4 \choose 4}$$

Comment: how did you rewrite it as $x^{11}...$ and why are we looking for the coefficient of $x^7$ when it was originally $x^{18}?

Comment: I just pulled out the common factors, $x$ from the first term and $(x^2)^5$ from the second.  That gives us the first $11$ powers of $x$ we need, so we only need $7$ more.

Comment: okay, this solution seems much simpler than the one posted above

Comment: and for this is it $$\frac{12!}{(12-5)!5!}$$ or $$\frac{12!}{(12-5)!}$$ when calculating that last line?

Comment: ${n \choose r}=\frac {n!}{r!(n-r)!}$, so the first

Comment: awesome i will work those all out and that will give me the final answer, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your expression can be rewritten as $$x(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)\cdot (x^2(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots)) ^5$$
$$=x(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)\cdot x^{10}(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots) ^5$$
$$=x^{11}(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)\cdot (1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots) ^5$$
The two expressions in the brackets are finite and an infinite GP respectively.  Hence by formula for sum of GP we have
$$=x^{11}\cdot \left(\frac {1-x^5}{1-x}\right). \left(\frac {1}{1-x}\right) ^5$$
$$=x^{11}.\left (\frac {1-x^5}{(1-x)^6}\right) $$
$$=\left (\frac {x^{11}-x^{16}}{(1-x)^6}\right) $$
Now using the [negative binomial series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NegativeBinomialSeries.html) we need to find coefficient of $x^7$ and $x^2$ because we already have $x^{11} $ and $x^{16}$ in the numerator.

So using negative binomial series we get the answer as $$\binom {12}{5}- \binom {7}{2}=771$$

Comment: the answer below seems to have more things to subtract have you gone wrong somewhere?

Comment: @jh123 check Ross Millikan and my answer.  Use hockey stick identity for his last three terms of the answer to get the last term of my answer while the first terms of both of us are same.$$\binom {12}{5}-\left(\binom {6}{4}+ \binom {5}{4}+\binom {4}{4}\right) =\binom {12}{5}-\binom {7}{5}=\binom {12}{5}-\binom {7}{2}$$

Comment: okay so both of these answers are correct then? i haven't seen that method before

Comment: @jh123 I added a link for negative binomial series in my answer.  If you want,  you can check on that site to learn more or just search on Google about it. And yes both the answers are same and correct

Comment: awesome thanks, and when evaluating yours do i use $$\frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}$$ so for example $$\frac{12}{(12-5)!5!}$$

Comment: by the way what is GP? geometric something?

Comment: @jh123 For your first question the answer is yes.  While for the second,  GP means Geometric Progression. For more information about it refer to.        https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression

Comment: alright thanks for everything you really helped out!

Answer (score 1):

Edit: So it looks like this could have been done much easier by factoring first. I'll leave this answer here in the event that this may be useful to someone with a related problem

Well we can get $x^{18}$ in our equation whenever we multiply terms together who's exponents will add to $18$. The left part of the equation will add in $1,2,3,4,5$ so we need to find the coefficients on the left side who's terms are $x^{17}, x^{16}, x^{15}, x^{14}, x^{13}$

Now to find each coefficient, we need to find all the sets of $5$ numbers in $[2,k]$ that sum to our exponents listed prior. I'll do $13$, for example.
$$
13 = 2+2+2+2+5
$$
$$
13 = 2+2+2+3+4
$$
$$
13 = 2+2+3+3+3
$$
Those are (hopefully I missed none), all the sums that sum to our exponent. now since these 13's can be got by multiplying any order of these terms, we need to see how many combinations these have by using the formula $\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!...k_n!}$ so,
$$
2+2+2+2+5 \rightarrow \dfrac{5!}{4!1!} = 5
$$
$$
2+2+2+3+4 \rightarrow \dfrac{5!}{3!1!1!} = 20
$$
$$
2+2+3+3+3 \rightarrow \dfrac{5!}{2!3!} = 10
$$

So summing this up we get that $5+20+10=35$, therefore the coefficient in front of our term becomes $35x^{13}$. When we finally multiply that out by the right side to get $x^5\cdot35x^{13} = 35x^{18}$.

Now in order to finish the problem, you must apply this process to $x^{14}, x^{15}, x^{16}, x^{17}$, and sum their respective coefficients. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your help! if you factored it first would you get the same answer?

Comment: Yes, I didn't realize and went about it the long way haha

Comment: well thanks for taking some time to help me out!